# function similar to advance that returns an iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Is there a function similar to advance, but will return an iterator instead of having a `void` return type? I *want* to have a function call like:

```
//...
[&value](InIter part_begin, std::size_t part_count)
        {
            difference_type ret = 
                std::count(part_begin, std::advance(part_begin,count), value);
            return ret;
        },
```

but advance is a `void` return type function, so i'm currently doing

```
//...
[&value](InIter part_begin, std::size_t part_count)
        {
            InIter end = part_begin;
            std::advance(end,part_count);
            difference_type ret = std::count(part_begin, end, value);
            return ret;
        },
```

it's important to note I **cannot** just do `part_begin + count`, this will not work for some of the iterators I am working with which forces me to currently use `std::advance`. Is there any cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [std::next](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) to get an iterator advanced by a given number of elements. In contrast to `std::advance`, `std::next` does not change the passed iterator itself.

```
[&value](InIter part_begin, std::size_t count) {
        difference_type ret = 
            std::count(part_begin, std::next(part_begin,count), value);
        return ret;
    },
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's called [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next). It doesn't modify its argument.